# Can't remove iis from Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, uninstall, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to uninstall IIS from Windows Server R2. I tried Service Manager -> Remove Roles and Features, uninstalling ran, the restart computer, but it's still there. I tried also to do it by PowerShell:

```
Import-Module ServerManager    
Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Server -restart
```

but without success too.

I think some local services prevent uninstalling, I should disable them, but not sure which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have installed the large Update KB2919355 install the following Update to fix the issue:

**You are unable to uninstall IIS after you install KB2919355 in Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2957390/en-us

> *Consider the following scenario:*
>
> You have a computer that is running Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2.
>    You have update 2919355 and Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) installed on the computer.
>    You try to uninstall IIS.
>
> **In this scenario, the uninstallation fails.** Additionally, IIS is rolled back and may not function correctly.
>
> **To resolve this issue, install the update that is described in this article** before uninstalling IIS.

**Download:**
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=90315dce-b104-4387-a7b8-27e4d4a699aa

Comment: okay, it worked