# Getting error 0x80070002 when I try to install IIS in Windows Features

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, iis

Here's exactly what happens: I go to Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off. Then, check the box for IIS, and hit OK.

[image]

It seems to be installing for a second then shows these error messages and closes out.

[image]

[image]

All it says that's slightly helpful is "The system can not find the file specified."

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro on a Dell Inspiron 660s.

Comment: Have you run an `SFC` check yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't remove iis from Windows Server 2012 R2](http://superuser.com/questions/743568/cant-remove-iis-from-windows-server-2012-r2)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, it's for a different operating system, and people who search for this question might not search for this problem on Windows Server 2012 R2. By the number of people this problem may apply to, this makes a big difference.

Comment: the KB states that the issue occurs in 8.1 and 2012R2, it is the SAME issue.

Comment: Stiil, the title of the question only applies to server owners. These could easily be a common issue, and I didn't find any answers for Windows 8.1 on here. Could I just link to the Windows Server question in mine where it says "duplicate of (etc.)"?

Answer (score 1):

After running an `sfc /SCANNOW`, it said I had a pending operation that required me to restart my computer before scanning.

When I restarted, I got some message on boot (too fast to read) and when it booted up it said `We couldn't complete the features - Undoing changes`.

When I checked Windows Features, IIS was installed. This must've happened because I had uninstalled it earlier and something went wrong with that.

When I went to uninstall it, it failed and gave me the same message saying that it couldn't complete the features.

I did some research and found out this is a problem with the Windows 8.1 April Update. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2957390