# Remove IIS from Win Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I'd like to remove IIS from Windows Server 2012 R2, but when I go to `Add Roles and Features` the option for `Web Server (IIS)` is greyed out and I can't un-tick it.

I've installed all the updates Windows suggested via Windows Update.

I found this: [Can't remove iis from Windows Server 2012 R2](https://superuser.com/questions/743568/cant-remove-iis-from-windows-server-2012-r2)

...but when I download and run that update I get:

> The update is not applicable to your computer.

Why am I not able to remove IIS..? How can I uninstall it..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, although lots of people said to go to `Add Roles and Features` and un-tick IIS, there is actually an option called `Remove Roles and Features`, which worked.

Comment: Yes, you open the "Add Roles and Features" wizard and you can see the "Remove Roles and Features" option on the first screen. Very easy to miss.